# Rails pre tags are inserting tabs for unknown reason

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

In one of my views I have the following code with this exact indentation...

```
<h2>TEST</h2>
<p>This is my code...</p>
<br/><br/>
<pre>
Testing
1
  2
    3
</pre>
```

However it is rendering like this:
[image]

Note that everything in the `pre` tag is indented beyond where the rest of the code is. I cannot figure out why.

Comment: You might have a margin or padding set on the pre element in your CSS or are they text (can you click and drag to select it?

Comment: Is this the actual html copied from your browser? Do you use haml to generate the view?

Answer (score 0):

This looks to me like a CSS issue. Can you check the styling of the pre tag, perhaps by examining it in the browser's debugger (e.g., Firebug or the Chrome debugger)?

You might also try putting your HTML in a standalone file (e.g., test.html), opening it with the browser, and seeing if it looks the same. If it doesn't, then there's probably a stylesheet in your application that's changing how you expect the pre tag to be styled.